# Verification of computation of e

Tags: c++, math, python-2.7

I've written a program which calculates e and am working on a world record computation. How would I verify a computation with more decimal places than any other existing computation? How would I program that in C++/Python?

Comment: Questions are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming.

Comment: http://apod.nasa.gov/htmltest/gifcity/e.2mil - 2,000,000 places - hopefully that is enough.

Comment: @user2442780 Where did you get your algorithm that you think is going to let you break the world record number of digits of `e`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem of precise calculations is to proove that your result is correct. in case of `e` if you say that your algorithm will print `e` with **n** decimal digits means that you can proove by means of mathematics that your number differs form the [Euler number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_number) not more than by 10E-n.
In other words, before writing a program you have to develop an algorithm and proove it's correctness.

Comment: That is insufficient. It's easy to write a program to compute e correctly. It's hard to verify that the result is correct. Given that there will likely be on the order of a billion digits and given the error rate of standard memory... OTOH ECC RAM should eliminate that problem, but then you still want to confirm such a result in some way.

Comment: I don't see any problems in providing enough precision in the calculations since you don't use `double` and `float`. You can use other data types which are specially designed for precise calculations (or write your own). I don't think that it is too easy to write a program that calculates `e` with 2kk digits and works fast enough.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see any usable Euler number identities which would enable you to quickly check the validity of your computation. In that case, I think that what you will have to live with is to check the first (millions) of decimal places against the known ground truth, and if it fits you will claim that your algorithm is working correctly. This is what is sometimes called "known cases" in the [Unit testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) frameworks.

Comment: I agree with ondav, if you don't encounter error with the first world-known maximum number of digits, then you should just trust your algorithm. Do you also beat performance in your computation ? (that should be a really hard task..)

Comment: This is not an answer to the question that was actually asked.  Perhaps this should be a comment instead.

Comment: @John Dibling: Please educate me, I am a beginner on SO. Does this mean that if the question does not have a constructive answer (= algorithm), it must not be answered? I posted this as an answer because this **is** an answer: in absence of usable math identities for Euler number, what you do is you verify your algo on what you have. Unit testing uses this for ages ("known cases"). In other words, it is not that I do not know the answer. I think that I know the answer, and the answer is that you must live with checking those known decimal places.

Comment: @ondav:  Perhaps I misunderstood your answer.  Your comment has served to clarify it in my mind quite a bit.  Perhaps you can incorporate some of your comment in to your answer.  If you can, then I can remove my downvote.

Comment: @JohnDibling And if you refer to C++/Python part, this was added by editing the original question only after I posted the answer.

Comment: @JohnDibling Done, thnx for suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You should copy suspectus' link into a .txt file and then write a program that uses fstream to compare each element digit by digit just to check if you've gotten the first 2 million decimals right. edit: I've written a program that would allow you to do that, edit the filename string so that it matches and have your algorithm put its numbers into the e_my_algorithm string.

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
fstream in;
string filename = "C:\\Users\\Aaron\\Desktop\\TXT.txt";
string e_known;
string e_my_algorithm;
in.open(filename);
while(in.good())
{
 e_known += in.get();  
}
in.close();
auto itk = e_known.begin();
auto ite = e_my_algorithm.begin();

while(itk != e_known.end() - 1)
{
if(*itk++ != *ite++)
{
cout << "failure" << endl; 
break;
}
}

return 0;
}
```

Beyond that you would need a background in mathematics to prove that your algorithm accurately approximates e to n digits. In particular you should study Real Analysis:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_analysis

The mathematical constant e is something the mathematics profession thoroughly understands so chances are any algorithm you come up with is already known to mathematicians.  So you should probably just look for an existing method to approximate e and code that.

If you're really serious about it, check this out, apparently someone was able to break the world record on an overclocked desktop computer:
http://www.numberworld.org/misc_runs/e-500b.html

he used the taylor series expansion:
e = 1/(0!) + 1/1(!) + 1/(2!) + 1/(3!) + 1/(4!)...